# Saving list of variables containig Keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gzip, pickle

I have a list of variables which contains several Keras models. I am going to save it via:

```
with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as handle:
    cPickle.dump(list_of_vars, handle)
handle.close()
```

But:

```
ImportError: h5py must be installed in order to save a model.
```

However, I have currently installed `h5py`.
I need to compress the save variables.

Answer (score 0):

As the error clear stats that you need to install `h5py` in order to save or load model.

Please run the below code to install `h5py` and  to resolve this error.

```
!pip install h5py
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already installed all packages.